# iOS Itunes Music Tagging/Playlist Creator

Tags: music, ios, media-manager, metadata-editor, itunes

I am looking for an app that provides functionality for either directly or indirectly tagging  songs as I play them on my iOS device. Currently, I believe that the only direct editing of song metadata is available through the "star rating" system contained in Music.app.  It may be that Apple has not published APIs for such content, but I wonder if anyone has come up with a workaround -- e.g., a tagging system that can be exported to text and then imported into itunes?

If the answer is that I need to abandon itunes in order to get this functionality, that's fine too.

In sum:

- on-the-fly song tagging
- ideally, including ability to pre-define tags and apply by button, etc. rather than having to manually edit ID3 tags each time.

Comment: I don't think there would be such an app since ID3 tags come from the mp3 files and that won't be something that Apple would like to have manipulated in its iOS devices. However I'm interested in knowing the answer if there are any apps for this already.

Comment: @Neeku Thanks -- I agree it is unlikely, because you would think it would be easy to find if the functionality existed.  But the fact that this type of functionality is so prevalent in Android makes me think that there might be enterprising app writers that might be trying to figure out a workaround, hence my question.

Comment: Oh! So Android has it?!! By the way I just remembered a menu item from iTunes where you could let it update your song info from the Internet, it must be the ID3, however you probably know that Apple crunches music files and manipulates them to fit in its library. So usually you won't have access to the actual mp: file! :-/

Comment: @Neeku -- yeah, I don't even need to access the actual mp3 file.  If all it did was allow you to easily add custom tags to songs in the itunes library that would be just fine, too.  You can do star ratings that will sync back to the library, so there's at least some ability to manipulate now.

Comment: Right. I've found a few apps out there that I forgot to post here yesterday! Will get back to this once I get some work done in the office! :D